# Typescript type checking not recognize Puppeteer Element method

Tags: typescript

Having the following code

```
   const [button] = await page.$x(`//div[@class='QS5gu sy4vM'][contains(., 'Accept all')]`)
   await button.click()
```

Typescript is throwing an issue when hovering on button.click()
`The 'this' context of type 'ElementHandle<Node>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'ElementHandle<Element>'.`

Indeed the page.$x signature is `ElementHandle<Node>` but I don't understand why is throwing this error.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

```
await button.evaluate((node) => (node as HTMLElement).click()
```